# Using NodeJS and async.queue to download and save lots of images to local disk

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, download

OK I have a NodeJS app and I'm trying to download lots of images from a web server (about 500 for now but the number will increase). The problem I get is a "Unhandled stream error in pipe Error: EMFILE" because it seems that too much files get opened at the same time.

So I'm trying to use async.queue to process files by batches of 20. But I still get the error.

```
SomeModel.find({}, function(err, photos){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {

        photos.forEach(function(photo){

            var url = photo.PhotoURL;
            var image = url.replace('http://someurl.com/media.ashx?id=', '').replace('&otherstuffattheend', '.jpg');
            photo.target = image;

            var q = async.queue(function (task) {
                request
                    .get(task.PhotoURL)
                    .on('response', function(response) {
                        console.log(task.PhotoURL + ' : ' + response.statusCode, response.headers['content-type']);
                        console.log(task.target);
                    })
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(task.target));
            }, 20);

            q.push(photo, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

            q.drain = function() {
                console.log('Done.')
            }

        });
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong ? Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new queue for each photo and each queue receives just one photo. Instead, only create a queue once (outside of the `forEach()`) and push the photo objects to it. You're also missing the callback in your task handler. For example:

```
var q = async.queue(function(task, cb) {
  request
    .get(task.PhotoURL)
    .on('response', function(response) {
      console.log(task.PhotoURL + ' : ' + response.statusCode, response.headers['content-type']);
      console.log(task.target);
      // the call to `cb` could instead be made on the file stream's `finish` event
      // if you want to wait until it all gets flushed to disk before consuming the
      // next task in the queue
      cb();
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      cb(err);
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(task.target));
}, 20);

q.drain = function() {
  console.log('Done.')
};

photos.forEach(function(photo) {
  var url = photo.PhotoURL;
  var image = url.replace('http://someurl.com/media.ashx?id=', '').replace('&otherstuffattheend', '.jpg');
  photo.target = image;

  q.push(photo, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```